# Can't attach frida function to android native lib function

Tags: javascript, android, frida

I'm building a frida js script that reads a json object containing directives to where to attach frida functions inside a native lib in an android APK. If I hardcode the libname and function name I can successfully attach to the function when it runs inside the app but for some reason I don't know why when I read the names from the json object the attachment doesn't occur. Assuming that I want to attach to a function named `Java_sg_vantagepoint_uncrackable3_CodeCheck_bar` inside `libfoo.so`.

The code that runs successfully:

```
Interceptor.attach(Module.findExportByName("libfoo.so", "Java_sg_vantagepoint_uncrackable3_CodeCheck_bar"), {
    onEnter: function(args){
        console.log('libfoo.so::Java_sg_vantagepoint_uncrackable3_CodeCheck_bar') 
        // this is logged when the function runs in the APP
        if(args){
            for(var arg in args){
                console.log('args[' + arg + ']:')
                console.log('Java_sg_vantagepoint_uncrackable3_CodeCheck_bar::args[arg] ' + args[arg])}

        }
    },
    onLeave: function(args){
        console.log('Leaving Java_sg_vantagepoint_uncrackable3_CodeCheck_bar...')
    }
}
)
```

The code that doesn't work:

```
var params = {
    "libs": ["libfoo.so"]
}
for(var lib in params.libs)
{
    const currentLib = params.libs[lib]
    Module.ensureInitialized(currentLib)
    console.log('current lib: ' + currentLib)
    var libExports = Module.load(currentLib).enumerateExports()
    for(var i in libExports)
    {
        var currentLibExport = libExports[i]
        if(currentLibExport.name.toLowerCase().includes('java'))
        {
            console.log('attaching to export: ' + currentLib + '::' + currentLibExport.name + ' at address: ' + currentLibExport.address)
            Interceptor.attach(currentLibExport.address, {
                onEnter: function(args){
                    console.log('onEnter ' + currentLib + '::' + currentLibExport.name)
                    if(args){
                        for(var arg in args){
                            console.log(currentLib + '::' + currentLibExport.name + '::args[arg] ' + args[arg])
                        }

                    } else
                    {
                        console.log('no args for ' + currentLib + '::' + currentLibExport.name)
                    }
                },
                onLeave: function(args){
                    console.log('onLeave ' + currentLib + '::' + currentLibExport.name )
                }
            }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Not only this doesn't attach to the function named `Java_sg_vantagepoint_uncrackable3_CodeCheck_bar` but even stranger during runtime it is logged the following:

> onEnter libfoo.so::main
>   onLeave libfoo.so::main

which for me makes no sense because I didn't attach to the `main` function

Reference: https://www.frida.re/docs/javascript-api/#module

Comment: Just to be sure I would not rely on the `libExports[i]` variable inside your loop and especially in the onEnter/onLeave methods. Inside yoir loop copy it to a local variable and use that instead. Otherwise you never know if Javascript gets your intention that you want to access the ``libExports[i]` at the time you intercepted the method and not the actual value of i (if te loop continues i changes and may be the last exported method is `libfoo.so::main`?

Comment: So, I've changed the access to `libExports[i]` and updated my question. Btw, no, `libfoo.so::main` is not the last export in the loop

Comment: @Robert is right, there's 100% something wrong with currentLibExport. You can't redeclare it using ``var`` on each loop iteration, it's not scoped like ``let`` in ES6.
Entering onEnter will take whatever value is in currentLibExport instead of the value at the time you defined the hook calling Interceptor.attach.